# Second Login Prompt on RDWeb Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdweb

I have server 2012 r2 setup as a virtual host. I have setup 2 virtual servers using hyper-v...

The 2 setup are a domain controller and an RDP server both 2012 r2. I have then setup RDWeb. I can login to see the links for the resources, clicking on the links downloads the remote app and then it asks for credentials again.... I know it is an easy answer, what is it that I am missing?

Here are pictures of what it looks like. In the secondary login picture the top image was under the bottom one

Interestingly enough I also have an error message saying permission denied in my new tab screen in fire fox.

[I login just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYBWw.png)

[Secondary Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yd9B.png)

Comment: you can store your login credentials in your `control panel > credential manager` then it shouldn't prompt for secondary login anymore

Comment: Have you got a valid ssl and added it using the wizard

Comment: I do have a trusted SSL installed and it is working.

Comment: Regarding the store the credentials, are you referring to storing them on the client computer or the server? It also looks like it is looking for credentials on the RDP server not the domain controller....

Comment: @blenkhn on the client computer. i had the exact same issue. if you use Win 8.1 or Win 10 and a 2012 R2 Server, storing the User PW for the RDP Server should fix it. Storing those credentials should actually happen automatically but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @SimonS I just tried your suggestion on Firefox and it doesn't work